# How to put '-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m' parameters for a .jar in the service wrapper?

Tags: java, executable-jar, systemd, java-service-wrapper

I have a jar named *my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*. I have to pass *-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m* to the jar like

```
sudo java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I've created the *.sh* using above command. I use this single line bash script file in *my-app.service* to execute the .jar. Now I need to put everything in *.service* file. No *.sh* in picture. How to put those in the *.service* file? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/728951/systemd-giving-my-service-multiple-arguments

Comment: Hi Frederico, I went through the link you shared. Looks like I need a config file for my service. I assume that once I manage to put these memory allocation parameters in that config file, I shall be able to use those in myapp.service file. Please let me know if there are any guidelines for the same. Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: You can consider that file as you would any other configuration file. That's why it's in `/etc` in the example. Supposing your program is called "myserver" I would have a file called `/etc/myserver/vmconf.ini` containing those parameters and have the .service file refer to that